# Figure out which desktop is active at the moment from the Win service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, logoff

I have a Win service running under the SYSTEM account. In case the user logs out from the system, the service should detect this and restart particular application on the logon desktop (and stop itself in case than user closing this application manually). The obvious way for me is detect which desktop (*Default*, *ScreenSaver* or *Winlogon*) is active now, but it seems that `OpenInputDesktop` call doesn't work under the service.

Comment: What about Windows computers without any screen? Some servers are running some version of Windows and don't have any screen

Comment: Actually I meant this [desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/desktops) :) It could be Default, ScreenSaver, and Winlogon.

Comment: Desktops are owned by sessions. There may not be a (interactive) session at all. I'm pretty sure the actual solution to your problem is to register and respond to events through the SCM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services run in a different session than users do. Desktops (and other UI resources) belong to the Session they are created in, and cannot be accessed across session boundaries. So the service simply can't *directly* access a user's desktops at all.

To access a given user's desktop, you will have to run a separate process in that user's session, and that process can then communicate back to the service process as needed via any IPC mechanism of your choosing.

The service can monitor for `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` events from the SCM to detect user logins/logouts, and spawn a process in a desired user session by using `WTSQueryUserToken()` and `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` is what I looked.